# Filebeat: how to create new field from the path?

Tags: filebeat

i would like to add new field extracted from the path what will be used. I have two path, see below.

```
      paths:
    - /home/*/app/logs/*.log
   # - /home/v209/app/logs/*.log
   # - /home/v146/app/logs/*.log 

  fields:
    campaign: v209
  fields_under_root: true
```

i would like to create new field **campaign** only with folder name like v209 or v146 any idea, how to do this in filebeads?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which filebeat version are you using?

Comment: filebeat version 7.17.3 (amd64), libbeat 7.17.3 [1993ee88a11cb34f61a1fb45c7c3cf50533682cb built 2022-04-19 09:27:20 +0000 UTC]. I can upgrade to 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three suggested solutions tested with Filebeat 7.1.3

**1) Static configuration of campaign field per input**

> ```
> filebeat.inputs:
>
> - type: filestream 
>   id: v209
>   paths:
>     - "/home/v209/app/logs/*.log"
>   fields:
>     campaign: v209
>   fields_under_root: true
>
> - type: filestream 
>   id: v146
>   paths:
>     - "/home/v146/app/logs/*.log"
>   fields:
>     campaign: v146
>   fields_under_root: true
>
> output.console:
>   pretty: true
> ```

**Explanation**: This solution is simple. Each file input will have a field set (campaign) based on a static config.

**Pros/Cons**: This option has the problem of having to add a new campaign field every time you add a new path. For dynamic environments, this can pose a serious operational problem but it's dead simple to implement.

**2) Dynamically extract campaign name from file path**

> ```
> processors:
> - dissect:
>     tokenizer: "/%{key1}/%{campaign}/%{key3}/%{key4}/%{key5}"
>     field: "log.file.path"
>     target_prefix: ""  
> - drop_fields:
>     when:
>       has_fields: ['key1','key3','key4','key5']
>     fields: ['key1','key3','key4','key5']
> ```

**Explanation**: These processors work on top of your filestream or log input messages. The dissect processor will tokenize your path string and extract each element of your full path. The drop_fields processor will remove all fields of no interest and only keep the second path element (campaign id).

**Pros/Cons**: Assuming your path structures are stable, with this solution you don't have to do anything when new files appear under `/home/*/app/logs/*.log`

**3) Script your way around**

If you wish to setup a more custom parsing logic, I'd suggest trying out the script processor and hack your way until your requirements are met:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/processor-script.html

Comment: I noticed you're using the `log` input. If you wish to continue so, just change `filestream` to `log` and remove the `id` configuration which does not exist in the `log` input.

Comment: Thank you so much, number 2 is what i needed!

Comment: Cool, please accept the answer for the posteriority.

Comment: Why create the additional keys just to throw them away? Can't we just do something like `tokenizer: "/path/to/logs/%{campaign}/further/path"`?